# How to restore my Z8 android dual SIM card phone

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

My Z8 informed me that a lot of files were not responding and kept me in a continual loop! Please understand that I am not that tech savvy so I am here asking for help in the simplest terms possible. I once followed y our instructions to use  n power button and volume button and got to c prompt and removed a pin code. I was hoping that you can reinstruct me on how and maybe the phone can be restarted or you can tell me how to reinstall drivers, IOS, UK etc to make it work please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide info about which Z8 you have. From what I checked, many companies have a model named Z8.

Anyhow, you should be able to fix most software issues by resetting the phone to factory state. That means you'll lose all user data. So, backup everything that you possibly can.

Then boot your device into recovery mode. The procedure may differ from device to device. But for most, the following combo works from a powered off state:

Press and hold *Power* and *Volume Up* keys. Release the power key upon vibration, but keep on holding the volume up key till you reach the recovery mode.

You can do "Factory Reset" or "Wipe Data" or something similar from the recovery to bring everything to the factory state.